# JSF - Validate Form Using JavaScript Before Submitting With Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, forms, jsf

My code looks (*somewhat*) like this -

```
<h:form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return ValidateForm();">
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{someClass.someMethod()}"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

This works fine. However now I wish to submit the form with ajax but before that also want to validate the form using JavaScript.

I tried this but didn't work

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{someClass.someMethod()}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="message" onevent="ValidateForm" />
</h:commandButton>
```

I want to know if there is any way we could validate the JSF form and if it returns true only then submit the form with Ajax. Any help would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: That is called Client-Side-Validation, for which both PrimeFaces and the 'end-of-life' RichFaces have solutions. Do not forget to ALWAYS also check server side, so a solution that automagically integrates the two is to be preferred (do not start using a plain jquery solution).

Comment: @Kukeltje yes server side validation is already in place. Was just wondering if client side too is possible

Comment: See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase more specifically https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/

Comment: Or do you already have CSV (onSubmit()), and it just does not work with 'ajax'?

Comment: I am afraid using PrimeFaces is too much at this point of time since facing extremely tight deadline. Not sure what you mean by CSV?

Comment: Click the second link in my comment... you'll directly know (and it is also sort of in my first comment ;-)) And If I remember correctly, PrimeFaces CSV should work without using any other component of PrimeFaces...

Comment: thanks a lot.. will surely try this